# no matching function for call to

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n;

void displaysum(double mat[n][n])
{
  double sum= 0;
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    sum += mat[j][j];
  cout<<"Sum of Diagnols Elements is \n"<<sum;
}

int main()
{
  cout << "what are the number of rows or column in the matrix" << endl;
  cin >> n;    
  double matrix[n][n];
  for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
  {
    for (int column = 0; column < n; column++)
      cin >> matrix[row][column];
  }

  displaysum(matrix)
  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why I get an error for no matching function to call in`XCODE`. Even if I try to change the variable in my function prototype it still gives me the same error.

Comment: with `double matrix[n][n]` you're trying to create a dynamic size array. This needs to be done with `new`

Comment: It still gives me error for no matching function

Comment: You're missing semicolon in this statement: `displaysum(matrix)`.

Comment: i figured it out it still gives me the same error

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why I get an error for no matching function to call in`XCODE`.

The basic issue is that C++ wants the second dimension to be constant at compile-time for the sake of type-checking. If you want to get around this you'll have to use pointers (AFAIK). You can make this work by changing the declaration of `displaysum` to

```
void displaysum(double **mat)
```

and making appropriate allocations for `matrix` in the original function.

If you don't like this, well, welcome to C++'s type system. In the function declaration, `double mat[n][n]` is seen as `double (*)[n]`. This actually makes sense, but why it doesn't see `matrix` as being of that type is because `n` isn't constant. You can change the call

```
displaysum(matrix);
```

to this:

```
displaysum(static_cast<double (*)[n]>(matrix);
```

and receive the curious error

```
static_cast from 'double (*)[n]' to 'double (*)[n]' is not allowed
```

(and that's not the strangest error you'll get out of the type system)